# Roadmap in reveal.js Quarto

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, reveal.js, quarto

I am preparing a presentation in Quarto reveal.js. I would like to have a roadmap to be shown at the top or at the bottom of each slide. Does someone know how to do it? Thanks, Marianna